# Deployment Stuck in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 with xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

While deploying the app in visual basic 2015 update 3, it gets stuck.

- When running the emulator initially and then deploying the app it opens another emulator and becomes deadlocked.
- It also becomes stuck when simply deploying the app without opening the emulator.

Although the app did build successfully: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITyJo.png).

Comment: try to remove the app before trying to re-deploy it

Comment: how to remove the app from emulator?  Sorry i didn't get you :(

Comment: Just as you would remove it from a regular phone.

Comment: I tried with new app/ program that is demo app for checking the deployation. still it stuck.. please see the screenshot and do guide me for the same...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday.  Apparently there's an update coming for xamarin but Visual Studio errors out.  I would as Nika said make sure to remove the app from the emulator.  Once done go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other.  Once there click the Check Now link and get the latest stable update.  For some reason every time an Xamarin Update is coming Visual Studio errors out on me.  Or freezes for that matter.

Comment: remove the app from emulator ? by installing latest update for xamarin remove this error?

Comment: They just pushed another update out that fixes these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful with installing the latest update of Xamarin, as it does have a few bugs to work out (witnessed it firsthand with incredulous frustration). The problem might have to do with the Xamarin version you have installed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. If your version is 4.2.X (latest), you might experience more issues than just the 'error out'. I had to downgrade to 4.1.2 for everything to work properly again.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Previously it is working fine, But now it stuck. Please go through the attachment and do guide me for the same.. :(

Comment: @VickyKunal, first you need to check your Xamarin Version. You can go to Start > type Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features. Your Xamarin version should be listed on the installed applications' list. If it is 4.2.X (X means any number), then I suggest downgrading to Xamarin 4.1.2. To do that, you will need to go here: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads                              You will see a big Xamarin download button, don't click it. Click on the View all versions under it. Choose Windows and pick 4.1.2 (Released in August). Run after downloading.

Comment: I also advise you take this advise with a grain of salt. There is no guarantee that this method will fix your problem. But it's worth a shot if the problem persists.

Comment: I actually updated mine and it works just fine.  Xamarin pushed out two updates to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

1. t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZA5x.png)he path of your app is not too large.Simple create your project in any drive3 with one folder name only.

2.Update your SDK manager with latest aAPI 23/24.

3.In SDK manager update only that tool which is necessary.
   PFA the Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I too have had weirdness with the Visual Studio Emulator for Android and visual studio appearing to be stuck at the "Deploying ..." step trying to launch the app for debugging.

What I discovered is that restarting both the emulator and visual studio seems to make things better for me once it starts to do this.   Also, when debugging an app, it seems that exiting your app normally helps compared to when using the "Stop Debugging" button.   For example, I started my app twice and killed it w/ the "Stop Debugging" button, but couldn't deploy/start the app a 3rd time w/out a restart of visual studio and the emulator.

Am using VS 2015 Community edition w/ update 3.